# GoogleMapsDemo gives IllegalStateException

Tags: android, google-maps, android-maps

I have did all steps which is give at google but lastly it give's this

```
errorCaused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The meta-data tag in your app's AndroidManifest.xml does not have the right value.  Expected 4132500 but found 0.  You must have the following declaration within the <application> element:     <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

#### AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.googlemapsdemo"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <permission
        android:name="com.example.googlemapsdemo.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.example.googlemapsdemo.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="12"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <!-- Required to show current location -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

    <!-- Required OpenGL ES 2.0. for Maps V2 -->
    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.googlemapsdemo.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="AIzaSyBLHwjdXsQK0sszxfrkoncHlqU3d2mDJok" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

#### MainActivity.java:

```
package com.example.googlemapsdemo;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity 
{
    private GoogleMap googleMap;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        try 
        {
            // Loading map
            initilizeMap();

        } catch (Exception e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    /**
     * function to load map. If map is not created it will create it for you
     * */
    private void initilizeMap() 
    {
        if (googleMap == null) 
        {
            googleMap = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(
                    R.id.map)).getMap();

            // check if map is created successfully or not
            if (googleMap == null)
            {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Sorry! unable to create maps", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() 
    {
        super.onResume();
        initilizeMap();
    }
}
```

Comment: post your google-play-services_lib Manifest.

Answer (score 2):

manifest file

For eclipse add this :

```
<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" 
 android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

If you are using Android Studio(latest version) with gradle0.7+ then add this line:

```
<meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="Your Key" />
```

Answer (score 2):

**Add the Google Play services version to your app's manifest**

> Edit your application's AndroidManifest.xml file, and add the
>   following declaration within the element. This embeds the version of
>   Google Play services that the app was compiled with.

You just need to add `<meta-data>` under `<application>` tag into your `AndroidManifest.xml`

```
....<application>
    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"  
     android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
    </application>
```

Comment: why? Any particular reason? because latest document doesn't have such info.

Comment: @Paresh Mayani latest google play services requires a version name, which is to be mentioned using <meta-data .. /> inside AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: Now it seems like a perfect answer :)

Comment: Hi ,I did this in My application but i got again error Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: API key not found.  Check that <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY" android:value="your API key"/> is in the <application> element of AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: @user2193635 post your error and also post your google-play-services_lib Manifest.

Comment: I m taking about your google-play-services_lib Manifest. Have u imported google-play-services_lib into your project?