# GoogleMap Demo Project

Tags: android

In google map demo, in Eclipse I have this in the manifest file

```
<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" 
    android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

But I'm getting anerror

```
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: API key not found.  Check that <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY" android:value="your API key"/> is in the <application> element of AndroidManifest.xml
```

My manifest:

```
       <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
        <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            package="com.example.googlemapsdemo"
            android:versionCode="1"
            android:versionName="1.0" >

            <permission
                android:name="com.example.googlemapsdemo.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
                android:protectionLevel="signature" />

            <uses-permission              android:name="com.example.googlemapsdemo.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />

            <uses-sdk
                android:minSdkVersion="12"
                android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

            <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
            <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
            <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
            <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

            <!-- Required to show current location -->
            <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
            <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

            <!-- Required OpenGL ES 2.0. for Maps V2 -->
            <uses-feature
                android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
                android:required="true" />

            <application
                android:allowBackup="true"
                android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
                android:label="@string/app_name"
                android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
                <activity
                    android:name="com.example.googlemapsdemo.MainActivity"
                    android:label="@string/app_name" >
                    <intent-filter>
                        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                    </intent-filter>
                </activity>

                <meta-data
                    android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
                    android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
            </application>

        </manifest>
```

Lastly it also displays else part in Toast...meaning it receives map fragment object null
Please suggest where am I making a mistake:

```
package com.example.googlemapsdemo;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity 
{
    private GoogleMap googleMap;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        try 
        {
                // Loading map
                initilizeMap();

        } 
        catch (Exception e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    /**
     * function to load map. If map is not created it will create it for you
     * */
    private void initilizeMap() 
    {
        if (googleMap == null) 
        {
            googleMap = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(
                    R.id.map)).getMap();

            // check if map is created successfully or not
            if (googleMap == null)
            {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Sorry! unable to create maps", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() 
    {
        super.onResume();
        initilizeMap();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### After u added `google play service lib version`  add api key as metadata like this (as per new documentation for google mapv2)

```
<meta-data
                    android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
                    android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

 <!-- add this meta-data tag for api key-->
<meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="AIzaSyBLHwjdXsQK0sszxfrkoncHlqU3d2mDJok" />
```

[For more info read this](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start)........ [api key was taken from ur previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21397222/googlemapsdemo-gives-illegalstateexception)

Answer (score 0):

You already have the right Error description:

```
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: API key not found.  
Check that <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY" android:value="your API key"/> is in the <application> element of AndroidManifest.xml
```

Your Manifest is missing the following `meta-tag`:

```
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="@your api key"
        />
```

You have to go to the [`Google Api Console`](https://code.google.com/apis/console/b/0/?noredirect&pli=1#project:619925732253%3aoverview) and create a project. Then you can can create an `Android Key` in `API Access`.

On the google developers site you have a good introduction to [Obtain a Google Maps API Key](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start#obtain_a_google_maps_api_key).

Answer (score 0):

Check this link on Obtaining a Google Maps Android v1 API Key.

[Google Maps Android v1 API Key](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start#get_an_android_certificate_and_the_google_maps_api_key.)

Add generated API key to your manifest file.

Answer (score 0):

You forget to add the code of your API key in your manifest file . Just add the below lines in your manifest file inside  tag.

```
<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY" android:value="your API key"/>
```